# Flyway + Oracle issues with baseline

Tags: flyway

I'm trying to get flyway to work with a Spring Boot application and Oracle.
So far I have been successful in getting flyway working on several databases (postgreSQL, mysql, SQLServer) but on Oracle I keep getting in a chicken and egg problem.

If I run my app for the very first time, I get an error: `Found non-empty schema "SPRING" without metadata table! Use baseline() or set baselineOnMigrate to true to initialize the metadata table.`

I'm connecting with a user `spring` to a specific namespace configured on Oracle. and I'd like to have the `schema_version` table on the same namespace

So if I try to set `flyway.baseline-on-migrate=true` it does create the migration table, but then, it does not create any of the tables, as it says there's already a version 1 installed on the schema identified by `<< Flyway Baseline >>`

How can I get away from this chicken and egg issue? Seems to happen only with oracle, all other dbs, it worked straight on the first time.

So far I'm running it, the app fails, I then delete entries from the `schema_version` table and run it again.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to specify the schema in Spring Boot e.g.:

`flyway:
  schemas: SPRING`

Let's say, you have the following setup in Oracle XE:

`CREATE TABLESPACE SPRING DATAFILE 'spring.dbf' SIZE 40M ONLINE;
CREATE USER SPRING IDENTIFIED BY SPRING DEFAULT TABLESPACE SPRING TEMPORARY TABLESPACE TEMP;
GRANT CREATE SESSION, CREATE TABLE, CREATE SEQUENCE, UNLIMITED TABLESPACE TO SPRING;`

You should now be able to populate the database using the following Boot properties:

`spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe
    username: SPRING
    password: SPRING
flyway:
  schemas: SPRING`